# Linux grep/awk: Filter lines in a file, but clone (preserve or omit) a trailing newline at EOF

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

I would like to filter lines, e.g. using

```
grep -v keyword $file1 > $file2
```

but I would like the output file to have the same "end of file" situation as the input file, i.e. if file1 contains a trailing newline, then file2 should also contain a trailing newline, and only then.

Using 'grep' as above, file2 always contains a trailing newline even if file1 doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure?  Could you post minimal file content examples?  I just tried to reproduce it but `$file2` **did** have the same last line (empty or not).

Comment: My question was about the 'newline' character at the end of the last line, not about additional empty lines. An empty last line, including its 'newline' termination, will make it into file2 of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk for RT:

```
$ cat with_nl
a
x keyword y
c
$
$ cat without_nl
a
x keyword y
c$
$
$ awk '{ORS=RT} !/keyword/' with_nl
a
c
$ awk '{ORS=RT} !/keyword/' without_nl
a
c$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working perfectly. (ORS=Output Record Separator)